# pip freeze not listing all dependencies for virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have a python project that uses `virtualenv`. I have installed various packages using `pip install <package-name`> with the virtual environment activated. I now want to generate a list of these packages. I am using the command `pip freeze >requirements.txt` (again with the virtual environment activated) however when I open the file all I see is:

```
virtualenv==15.1.0
```

I don't see any of the other packages I have used. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked `which pip` at all stages to make sure pip was actually using the pip from the virtualenv? If, for instance, you use `sudo pip`, this will use the system's default pip (from `/usr/bin` usually if you are on linux dist).

Comment: @schwobaseggl it appears to be using the global pip at `/usr/local/bin/pip`. The path needs to be `/Users/kekearif/Documents/Python/FlaskWebDev/v1/flask/bin/pip` How would I change this?

Comment: If you aren't using sudo and the virtualenv is activated, something seems off, but you can always call the virtualenv's pip directly via its full path: `~/Documents/Python/FlaskWebDev/v1/flask/bin/pi‌​p install ...`